# Groupby and calculations based on specific row value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have data that looks like this:

```
d = {'id' : [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2],
     'levels': ['low', 'perfect', 'high', 'low', 'perfect', 'high'],
     'value': [1, 10, 13, 2, 10, 13]}

df = pd.DataFrame(d, columns=['id', 'levels', 'value'])
df = df.groupby(['id','levels'])[['value']].mean()
```

For each [id, levels], I want to find the difference between the `value` of the row and the `value` of the `perfect` row. It would look like this:

```
id | levels | value | penalty
1  | high   | 13    | 3
   | low    | 1     | 9
   | perfect| 10    | 0
2  | high   | 13    | 3
   | low    | 2     | 8
   | perfect| 10    | 0
```

For example, in the first row, you would subtract 13 from the perfect value, which is 10, to get 3.

So how do I make a calculation where I find the `perfect` value for each `[id, levels]`, and then find the differences?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Select the cross section of dataframe using [`xs`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.xs.html), then subtract this cross section from the given dataframe on `level=0`

```
df['penalty'] =  df['value'].sub(df['value'].xs('perfect', level=1)).abs()
```

---

```
            value  penalty
id levels                 
1  high        13        3
   low          1        9
   perfect     10        0
2  high        13        3
   low          2        8
   perfect     10        0
```

Answer (score 6):

You can try transform and then subtract and convert to absolute:

```
val = df.loc[df['levels'].eq('perfect').groupby(df['id']).transform('idxmax'),'value']
df['penalty'] = df['value'].sub(val.to_numpy()).abs()
```

---

```
print(df)

   id   levels  value  penalty
0   1      low      1        9
1   1  perfect     10        0
2   1     high     13        3
3   2      low      2        8
4   2  perfect     10        0
5   2     high     13        3
```